# G++ installed in /usr/local/bin links with libstdc++ installed in /usr/lib

Tags: c++, linux

So I built g++ and installed it with `make install`, and it installed in `/usr/local/bin`. The problem is, as I think, that compile-time symbols are used from `/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so`, and run-time, symbols are used from `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so`, and as `ldd` shows, it depends on `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so`. So how do I make executable depend on the right libstdc++?